# Why is my container-fluid div not including the box divs as well?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a dice with the help of bootstrap grid. Although I am not done with it yet, here is small snippet of code containing what I have written. When I am inspecting my webpage using dev tools (picture attached), my container-fluid div which basically includes all my code is not displaying to contain the box divs?
Can you explain me why so?
I have attached my HTML and CSS code as well.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(41, 36, 36);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bungee Spice', cursive;
  margin: auto;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.result {
  font-size: 500%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.box {
  width: 60%;
  height: 180%;
  /* padding-bottom: 60%; */
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}


/* .circle1 {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
} */


/* .box-row {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
} */

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  .result {
    font-size: 400%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .result {
    font-size: 300%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Spice&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="result">Welcome, <span class="playerName"></span></h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h2>You</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row box-row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle1"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row box-row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle4"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle5"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle6"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row box-row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle7"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle8"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle9"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h2>Computer</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle1"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle4"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle5"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle6"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle7"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle8"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
            <div class="circle9"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Roll</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Your issue comes from: `.box {height: 100%;}`. `height` in percentge can be tricky as they need a parent with a defined `height`. If you remove it, `.box` height will be part of your `.row` height. you could add `aspect-ratio: 1;` to your `.box` instead of the `height`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have commented out the only style that would apply to the dots inside of the yellow boxes, but in general, the issue is that the bootstrap grid doesn't inherit any height, and the height: 100% that you have defined comes out as 0. If you would change the .circle1 height to a fixed size or apply a height to the dots row, then it would show up.